# Forma estándar de inicializar un new char[size] con una cadena literal en C++

Tags: c++

Mi código funcionaba bien hasta que actualicé mi compilador mingw a la versión mas reciente (versión 8) para soportar c++17.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    char *frase = new char[14]{"El sol brillo"}; 
    
    std::cout << frase << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Este es el error que recibo:

```
ERROR: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
```

Entonces como hago para inicializar directamente el valor dinámico new char[size] con una cadena literal.

Comment: La forma estandar es no usar `new` y utilizar `std::string`.